# How to properly Inject an object in a view-model in order to navigate into a different view-model for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I found an example online by C# design pro on Page Navigation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CkHyDYeImjY. However, I am running into an issue when navigating between pages. I am trying to allow users to navigate to a different page when they click on Active Filter, which will call by a different user-control page inside a user-control page.
The initial user-control page is called by the Main Windows Button selection, shown on the program's left side. The image below shows the first user-control page when the user selects the Sales Submittal button, which displays two additional buttons.

[image]

I aim to show a different subpage when the User clicks the Active Filter button. I modified my NavigationVM model so that whenever the Sales Submittal button calls the SalesSubmittalCommand on the main window, the SubmittalVM gets created and passes an action object which gets stored in the SubmittalVM. This gets used by the View to invoke a change. BUT THIS IS NOT WORKING, AND IDK why.

My architecture is as the following:

## DataTemplate.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MTE_Price_Search.ViewModel"
                    xmlns:view="clr-namespace:MTE_Price_Search.View">

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:HomeVM}">
        <view:Home />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ProductVM}">
        <view:Products />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SubmittalVM}">
        <view:Submittal />
    </DataTemplate>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

## MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:NavigationVM />
    </Window.DataContext>
 <Grid>

        <!--// Window Border Code stuff//-->
        <Grid>

            <!--// Base Grid Code Stuff //-->
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="228" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="622" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  Width="228">
                <Border Background="#272B2F"
                        CornerRadius="20,0,0,20" />

                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Text="Azzurro"
                               Foreground="#FFC3C3C3"
                                FontSize="30"
                     />
                </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel Height="400"
                            Width="228">

                    <!--// Home //-->
                    <Menu:Btn Style="{StaticResource BtnStyle}"
                              Command="{Binding HomeCommand}"
                              IsChecked="True">

                        <Grid>

                            <Image Source="Images/img_home.png"
                                   Style="{StaticResource Image_Style}" />

                            <TextBlock Text="Home"
                                       Style="{StaticResource Text_Style}" />

                        </Grid>

                    </Menu:Btn>



                    <!--// Products //-->

                    <Menu:Btn Style="{StaticResource BtnStyle}"
                              Command="{Binding ProductsCommand}">

                        <Grid>

                            <Image Source="Images/img_product.png"
                                   Style="{StaticResource Image_Style}" />

                            <TextBlock Text="MTE Search"
                                       Style="{StaticResource Text_Style}" />

                        </Grid>

                    </Menu:Btn>

                    <!--// Project Submital // -->

                    <Menu:Btn Style="{StaticResource BtnStyle}"
                              Command="{Binding SalesSubmittalCommand}">

                        <Grid>

                            <Image Source="Images/img_Sales.png"
                                   Style="{StaticResource Image_Style}" />

                            <TextBlock Text="Sales Submittal"
                                       Style="{StaticResource Text_Style}" />

                        </Grid>

                    </Menu:Btn>  
                </StackPanel>

            </Grid>

            <Grid Grid.Column="1">

                <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                    <ContentControl x:Name="Pages" DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                                Content="{Binding CurrentView}" />
                </DockPanel>

            </Grid>

        </Grid>

        <Button x:Name="CloseApp"
                Style="{StaticResource ExitApp}"
                Click="CloseApp_Click" />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

## NavigationVM.cs

This is injected into Mainwindow. xaml by Window.Datacontent in the xaml view. The code below navigates between different views on the main window. (did not include the namespace)

```
  class NavigationVM : ViewModelBase
    {
        private object _currentView;
        public object CurrentView
        {
            get { return _currentView; }
            set { _currentView = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        public ICommand HomeCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand ProductsCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand SalesSubmittalCommand { get; set; }

        private void Home(object obj) => CurrentView = new HomeVM();
        private void Product(object obj) => CurrentView = new ProductVM();
        private void Submittal(object obj) => CurrentView = new SubmittalVM( OpenActiveFilter);


        private void OpenActiveFilter(object obj)
        {
            if (obj.ToString() == "ActiveFilter")
            {
                CurrentView = new ActiveFilterVM();
            }
        }

        public NavigationVM()
        {
            HomeCommand = new RelayCommand(Home);
            ProductsCommand = new RelayCommand(Product);
            SalesSubmittalCommand = new RelayCommand(Submittal);


            CurrentView = new HomeVM();
        }
    }
```

## Submittal View and View Model

When the Submittal Action command gets selected by the Navigation VM, it creates a new submittalVM which is tied to the Submittal View by the DataTemplate and in the View. The Submittal View calls Active filter button is binding via command to FilterNavigate Icommand, which is in the Submittal ViewModel.

### View

```
<UserControl x:Class="MTE_Price_Search.View.Submittal"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MTE_Price_Search.View"
             xmlns:Icon="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/iconpacks"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MTE_Price_Search.ViewModel"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="600"
             d:DesignWidth="622"
             Foreground="#FF212529"
             Style="{StaticResource Page_Style}">

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <vm:SubmittalVM />
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <Border CornerRadius="0,20,20,0" Margin="0,5,5,0">

        <Grid Margin="20">
            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Padding="0 20"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="{Binding ElementName=grid, Path=ActualWidth}">

                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">

                    <Button Padding="20" Width="230" Margin="15 0" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" Command="{Binding FilterNavigate}">
                        <Button.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="Button">
                                <Setter Property="Height" Value="300"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#e2e2e4"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FF0BCDFF" />
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FF07788D" Offset="0.9" />
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </Button.Style>

                        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <Icon:PackIconMaterial Width="50" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                   Kind="AirFilter" />
                            <TextBlock FontSize="18" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="0 30 0 0 " FontFamily="/Fonts/#Rubik Medium"
                                       Text="Active Filter"/>
                        </StackPanel>

                    </Button>

                    <!-- Copy and paste of first button just modified color, icon, and text -->


                </StackPanel>
                
            </ScrollViewer>

        </Grid>
        
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

### ViewModel

This command is then tied to another command that changes the inject action from the NavigationVM, or I think so.

```
class SubmittalVM : Utilities.ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly PageModel _pageModel;

    private readonly Action<object> navigate;

    //this command sets the readonly action object to activefilter
    private void OnNavigate(object obj) => navigate?.Invoke("ActiveFilter");
    public ICommand FilterNavigate { get; set; }

    public SubmittalVM(Action<object> navigate)
    {
        _pageModel = new PageModel();
        FilterNavigate = new RelayCommand(OnNavigate);
        this.navigate = navigate;

    }


}
```

However, this is not working and does not update the object CurrentView, which controls the Mainwindow content control.